# Search API Autocomplete not working with search_api_db

Tags: search

I have created a view page for search functionality. Following modules I have enabled:

```
Search API
Search views
Database search
Entity API
Views
Views UI
Ctools
```

[Search API Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_autocomplete)

I followed this [link](https://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages) to achieve search functionality. How to use [Search API Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_autocomplete) combined with above mentioned modules so that I get **auto-complete drop-down suggestions**.

Comment: I don't think it works with those modules - I've just done the same thing for a recent project and ended up coding that part myself because the modules couldn't handle it

Comment: Can you suggest, how have you done this coding part?

Comment: Sorry it's complicated, plus tuned for the specific site. Not something I can drop in, and not technically owned by me either. This is the library I used if it helps: https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/